# Having trouble with multidimensional array initialization

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn java and of course I'm a beginner. I am facing problem with initializing a multidimensional array. Here is the code I'm trying to write...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class one {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int p[][] = null;
        System.out.println("Type ur array here:");
        System.out.println("how many rows and column:");
        int row, colmn;
        Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        row = t.nextInt();
        colmn = r.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
            for(int v = 0; v <= colmn; v++){
                int j = u.nextInt();
                p[row][colmn] = j;
            }

        int a[][] = p;
        System.out.println("The given array:");
        y(a);

    }
    public static void y(int n[][]) {

        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(n[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Please someone correct this and provide me with sufficient knowledge I need.

Comment: You can initialize a multidimensional array with `int[][] p = new int[capacity][captacity];`

Comment: @August Or `int[][] p = new int[capacity][]` instead. Note that the second capacity can be left empty, in which case one can freely establish the second dimensional array with `p[index] = new int[capacity]`.

Comment: Also, ___please___ use descriptive variable names.

Comment: 4 different Scanner with the same input source? Just use one, that will be enough. Also `p[row][colmn]=j;` will overwrite the content of the former iteration. Use `p[i][v]=j` instead. And don't forget to initialize the array like August suggested.

Comment: thanks for the previous help,sorry to disturb,but I have a new problem ... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException    this is showing now,will you please take a look at the code .

Comment: If you initialize your array with the `row` and `colmn` variables then you can't loop over it as long `i` or `v` are smaller or *equal* than these values. So change `for(int i=0;i<=row;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i<row;i++)` and `for(int v=0;v<=colmn;v++)` to `for(int v=0;v<colmn;v++)`. Explanation: If `row` is 4 the array indices are from 0 to 3. If you loop until `i` is larger than `row` you will receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if `i` hits the 4.

Comment: Or to put it more simply, `new int[N]` has `N` elements, indexed from `0` to `N-1`.

Comment: still no luck!I'm showing you...(Type ur array here:
how many rows and column:
2
4
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at one.main(one.java:18)
)                                                                      this is happening when i input my first digit in array after declaring the row and column size.is that a problem,if you run the code for me and show me the corrections???

Comment: Post the __FULL exception  stack TRACE__... into the question

Comment: I don't even know where to begin...

Comment: @BlackMagic Your exception may come from this `p[row][colmn]=j;` command (according to the line number in your exception). Read my first comment about this command. Also don't forget that the last index of an array is `size - 1`.

Comment: Initialize the array using the column and row count (`int[][] p = new int[row][column];`), and then loop through the array using `<` instead of `<=` (Using `<=` will attempt to access an index equal to the arrays length, which doesn't exist!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to the code are mentioned in comments, but please see the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class one {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int p[][] = null;
        System.out.println("Type ur array here:");
        System.out.println("how many rows and column:");
        int row, colmn;
        Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Only one is required to read from standard input stream, instead of:
        // Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Use Scanner object "u":
        row = u.nextInt();
        colmn = u.nextInt();

        // Memory to array:
        p = new int[row][colmn];

        // Change '<=' to '<' as arrays are 0 index and will give index out of bounds exception ;
        // Or change 'p = new int[row][colmn];' to 'p = new int[row + 1][colmn + 1];'.
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int v = 0; v < colmn; v++){
                int j = u.nextInt();
                // Change indices to "i, v" instead of "row, colmn":
                p[i][v]=j;
            }

        }
        // Bad way to copy array as same reference is going to be used.
        // To copy array use the following:

        /* 
         * // int a[][] = p;
         * int[][] a = new int[row][colmn];
         * for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
         *     System.arraycopy(p[i], 0, a[i], 0, colmn);
         * }
         */

        int a[][] = p;
        System.out.println("The given array:");
        y(a);

    }
    public static void y(int n[][]){

        for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(n[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }

 }
```